What is the exact text string returned by ```syminfo.prefix``` for ETFs in the NYSE Arca exchange?
Question: What is the exact text string returned by syminfo.prefix for ETFs in the NYSE Arca exchange?
Context: syminfo.prefix contains the exchange of the current ticker. If you are using the free data plan it will generally return BATS for most US stocks and ETFs. However, if you have a paid data subscription for NASDAQ or NYSE data, syminfo.prefix will instead return NASDAQ for AAPL, NYSE for JPM, etc. I'm trying to a write a script that filters for ETFs in the NYSE Arca exchange so I need to know the EXACT text string that syminfo.prefix returns for NYSE Arca. For example:
    exchange = syminfo.prefix=="NASDAQ" ? 1 : 0

In the example above, what exact text string would I use for NYSE Arca instead of NASDAQ? I can't pull up this information since I lack a paid subscription to NYSE Arca, ie syminfo.prefix returns BATS. I checked the pinescript manual but it does not list all the possible values (exchanges) associated with syminfo.prefix. Does anyone know the correct text string?

The prefix for an ETF on NYSE Arca is "AMEX".
I don´t have a list of all exchanges but I can show you how to find this out.
I have a small dashboard for 8 stocks on my chart. I can change the stocks in the settings menu. This looks like this and the exchange prefix is displayed with the symbol.

If I want to change the symbol to an ETF, I restrict the search to Fund, USA and ETF. It then looks like this, there seem to be 3 different exchanges: NASDAQ, CBOE and NYSE Arca.

If you choose the one on the bottom, APLY on the NYSE Arca, the settigs menu shows the correct prefix, in this case AMEX.

If you want to try this for yourself - e.g. for mutual funds or REITs, there are other exchanges - all you need is an input.symbol() function in your script.

That seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

I have just found a more simple solution. When you open the Change Symbol Menu, delete any characters and use the up and down arrows to scroll through the list of symbols, it automatically adds the prefix. I never noticed this before...
